# What is happening with static variables in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, static

Today I found some unexpected behavior in PHP.
I was experimenting with a settings class which also includes database connection information.
The class looks something like this:

```
class Config
{
    static $dbHost = 'localhost';
    static $dbName = 'name';
    static $dbUser = 'user';
    static $dbPass = 'pass';
}
```

In a 'service locator' I configure a function to create a PDO connection when needed.
The code looks like this:

```
$this->configService('db', function (ServiceLocator $context) {
    return new \PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . Config::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . Config::$dbName . ';charset=utf8',
        Config::$dbUser,
        Config::$dbPass
    );
});
```

Then I thought: in case of an error a stacktrace might expose the content of the config class. So I will unset the password when the database connection is set:

```
$this->configService('db', function (ServiceLocator $context) {
    $password = Config::$dbPass;
    Config::$dbPass = '';

    return new \PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . Config::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . Config::$dbName . ';charset=utf8',
        Config::$dbUser,
        $password
    );
});
```

But this does not work, the password will be empty when PDO tries to connect.
I did some tests and it looks like PHP is always using late binding of static variables.

So my question is: what is going on here? Will PHP set the $password variable at the moment PDO is needing it (and Config::$dbPass === '')?

Edit: PHP v7.0.23

Comment: it seems working , maybe you call `configService` twice ?

Comment: I didn't think about checking if the code is called twice. And yes it is! :(

The router of the software is including a file twice... and I didn't notice it.

Comment: So you should use a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). this will ensure that your PDO will be instantiated only one time !

Comment: I don't think a Singleton pattern is the answer for a router that runs the same route twice.

Comment: So you want multiple instance of PDO ? Singleton has to be on PDO management.One instance of PDO don't mean you can't call it twice or more. if you want an example tell me.

Comment: Yes I understand that the Singleton pattern has some benefits. But it doesn't fix the problem of a router running the same route twice.

Comment: Maybe but this is an other problem. without code we can t help you

Answer (score 0):

Alexandre Painchaud hinted that the code might run twice. And yes it does.

The router is including the ServiceLocator twice :(

This has nothing to do with late binding.

Answer (score 0):

instead of clearing password use getter to get value from class? Basic stack trace shouldn't show class private property.

```
<?php
final class Config
{
    private $dbHost = 'localhost';
    private $dbName = 'name';
    private $dbUser = 'user';
    private $dbPass = 'pass';

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->dbPass;
    }
}

var_dump((new Config())->getPassword());
```